# Unable to update user profile data in database

Tags: cakephp

In my controller

```
public function profile() {
    $UserInfo = $this->Auth->user()
    if(!empty($this->data)) {
            print_r($this->data);
         $this->User->save($this->data);
    } 
    if(!empty($UserInfo['id'])){
        $this->data = $this->User->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$UserInfo['id'])));

    }

}
```

when i submit the data it is not submitted to db and i get only previous value.

Comment: what cakephp version? you need to always provide this information for getting correct answers.

Comment: @amit: Cake comes in with very handy debug() method, that can be turned of with debug level 0 (when in production) and on with debug level 1 or 2 (for development). You can replace your print_r with debug($this->data);

Answer (score 1):

Why are you querying the session here? of course this will always get you the old data again after the save.

Use the database as always, update the database again and only then overwrite the session maybe (You seem to be using cake 1.3):

```
public function profile() {
    $uid = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->data['User']['id'] = $uid;
        if ($this->User->save($this->data, true, array('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'id', ...))) {
            // if you rely on auth session data from the user, make sure to update that here
            $this->Session->write('Auth.User.email', $this->data['User']['email']); // etc
            ...
            // OK, redirect
        } else {
            // ERROR
        }
    } else {
        $this->data = $this->User->find('first', ...);
    }
}
```

As you can see I update the session keys that have been changed.

If you are using 2.x (which you did not specify as for now) you could also use

```
$this->Auth->login($this->request->data['User']); // must be the User array directly
```

although you will have to careful to pass all the data that has been in the session before.
If you plan on using login(), it would be better to find(first) the updated record again and pass this into login() then.

But personally, I prefer to only update the fields that actually changed.

see [Editing own account/profile](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/10/05/common-cakephp-problems-and-solutions/)

Comment: How about letting Auth write its own session ? $this->Auth->login($this->data['User']['id']);

Comment: Almost, a minor issue... It must be $this->request->data['User'] as login expects it to be a flat array (`$this->Session->write(self::$sessionKey, $user);`).

Comment: Since the data has already been saved, I am not sure if $this->request->data and $this->data will have much difference. I will have to check the cookbook, but I believe the only difference is that $this->request->data is Read/Write property and $this->data is read only. Have I missed something out ?

Comment: I used $this->data as I suspected 1.3 here. see the question. So only for 2.x I updated the bottom for the new login() method.